# XPATH: Ignore milli seconds from date

Tags: xpath

I am trying to extract using the following

```
<xsl:template match="//alarms:alarmRaisedTime">
        <xsl:variable name="secondsSince1970" select="(xs:dateTime(.) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')" />
        <xsl:element name="alarmRaisedTime" namespace="MY NAME SPACE">
            <xsl:value-of select="$secondsSince1970"/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Output I get is

```
<alarmRaisedTime>1367855105.001</alarmRaisedTime>
```

I would like to get the below given output (Note Milli Seconds is removed)

```
<alarmRaisedTime>1367855105</alarmRaisedTime>
```

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:substring-before($secondsSince1970,.)"/>
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

**Even simpler**:

```
floor($secondsSince1970)
```

By **[definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-floor)**:

> *The floor function returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) number that is not greater than the argument and that is an integer.*

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:substring-before($secondsSince1970,'.')"/>
```

The `.` in your expression refers to the context item `alarms:alarmsRaisedTime`